# Listview horizontal and vertical line visibility WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid, listbox

Can anyone please tell me how can I disable the `ListView` horizontal and vertical line visibility?

Like in `DataGrid` we use the property `gridLine=false`.

So is there any option for listview?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're using a `ListView` with a `GridView` set as the `View`, then the `ListView` doesn't show vertical or horizontal lines by default.

If you want to add horitzontal lines then you can change the border on the `ListViewItem`, e.g:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn ... />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    ...
```

If you want to add vertical lines then see [here](http://blog.bulatgafurov.name/2010/06/listview-horizontal-and-vertical.html) for more information.

Comment: devdigital i need to disable the lines of rows and column not to disable scroll bar.....

Comment: Sorry, misread the question, answer updated.

Comment: thanks all i have found the solution done myself..once again thanks.

Comment: Dead link for vertical lines.

Comment: Correct link for vertical lines: http://blog.bulatgafurov.name/2010/06/listview-horizontal-and-vertical.html

Comment: very, very nice